# Is there a way to tell if an image src is returning null inside of javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, dom

Is there anyway in javascript to test if a src of an image is actually hitting a real file?

My thought is that at some point in the DOM construction the browser has to realize that the file location is not returning a real file because it defaults to the broken file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function I use in my library for this incident:

```
function onImageError (source) {
    //NOTE: Image Error function 
    //Useage: <img src="" onerror="onImgError(this)" />

    source.src = "/public/images/global/backup_product.jpg"; // location of sample/error image
    source.onerror = ""; // disable onerror to prevent endless loop
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can leverage the [`onerror`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp) event for the image element.